# How can I use the MVC Model to Load, Change, then Save a record?

Tags: development, mvc

After googling,etc. I've arrived at the below code to *Add* a new Category to Joomla so that all the plugin events, etc. get done.

```
$basePath = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_categories';
require_once $basePath.'/models/category.php';
$catmodel = new CategoriesModelCategory(array('table_path' => $basePath.'/tables'));

$myArrayOfData = array('id'=>'0','title'='my title'...);
$catmodel->save($myArrayOfData);
```

As it is now, I use the same code to update the record, but instead of a fresh copy of the data array to add, I use SQL to get the existing record as an array, then modify and save the same way.

This "works", but doesn't seem like the right way to do it, so I'm curious how to load the Model using the id of the Category , then use it's methods to change/save.  I've tried following the code that executes when the Category Component does it, but too many things are going on for me to nail down how it's done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have the category ID which is stored in $id. You can instantiate the category model as you did it before:

```
$basePath = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_categories';
require_once $basePath . '/models/category.php';
$catModel = new CategoriesModelCategory(array('table_path' => $basePath . '/tables'));
$id = 11;
```

Now you have two methods:

## Method 1 - Without JTable Object

```
$item = $catModel->getItem($id);
$catModel->save('id' => $id, 'parent_id' => $item->parent_id, 'title' => 'My New Title'); // parent_id should be defined otherwise a warning will be displayed
```

## Method 2 - With JTable Object

```
$catTable = $catModel->getTable();
$catTable->load($id);
$catTable->title = 'My New Title';

$catTable->check();
$catTable->store();
```

### Note

Only with the first method, `onContentBeforeSave` and `onContentAfterSave` events will be fired.

Comment: Aha...loading the table!...always so obvious after the fact, lol...

Comment: I'm getting non-object errors with this code.  I've updated the question to incorporate your answer showing where.

Comment: @GDP, I modified my answer. Could you check it and tell us the result?

Comment: I get the error `CategoriesTableCategory::bind(*NULL*)`, but your modified answer is using jTable, not the Model as I'm looking for....will this fire the plugin events like onContentAfterSave?

Comment: @GDP, I've edited my answer and it works now. The `save` method is used to bind form to data; I replaced it with `check` and `store` methods. Now the table is called from the model, so you have the category model in your hands, too.

Comment: @GDP, Only with the first method, `onContentBeforeSave` and `onContentAfterSave` events will be fired.

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile(s) for your answer....all working as expected thanks to you!

Comment: You're welcome. Please note that by second method, you can fire `onContentBeforeSave` and `onContentAfterSave` events by `JEventDispatcher` object before and after `store()` function.